# Javascript 3 step signup script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a multi step form on codepen.io but when adding the requiered scripts and the javascript i get a error in google chrome `Uncaught TypeError: b.easing[this.easing] is not a function`. I also have the problem where when i press `next` the next field show up below the existing one.

heres my code:

```
<style>
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*form styles*/
#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;

  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}




</style>

<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>


  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>

</form>



<script>

//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
  if(animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show(); 
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50)+"%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
      next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
  if(animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show(); 
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({'left': left});
      previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
  return false;
})

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js" />
```

You can also see the codepen.io version here:
http://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz

i did not add css for `*`, `html`, or `body` because I already have css for them in a different stylesheet

*Edit: the error come first when you click `next` the first time, second form that show will have two buttons one for next and one for previous. none of them will work.
There is also a problem where it cuts off right after the form and wont display my footer, I belive im able to fix that one myself

Comment: Your codepen is working fine for me, Chrome 53, Firefox 47 and Edge 20.

Comment: codepen isnt mine, but thats what im trying to add to my website. but the code added above is what mine looks like. Im not 100% sure if i have placed it in right order or if it even mathers. Do you know if it might come in conflict with other javascript types? like `three.min.js` or `TweenMax.mi.js`

Comment: Is your code a literal copy paste of your html page? Where are the `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld to save space and get the most help i have not included the whole code because its so long and will make people mad (tried once before). Therefor i have only added the parts i am having problems with. If you want i can add everything to a codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there were a couple of mistakes.

Script tags aren't self closing tags. `<script src=""/>` won't work. Therefore, you must always write `<script src=""></script>`

You declared both `jQuery` and `Easing` after running the script. This is like trying to start a car before putting the engine in.

The example below should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*form styles*/
#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;

  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>





<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>


  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<script>

//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
  if(animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show(); 
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50)+"%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
      next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
  if(animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show(); 
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({'left': left});
      previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
  return false;
})

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so that was the problem. hmm realy thought `<script>` was a self closing tag, and I didnt even notice i had the closing tag `</script>` in my `<head>`.

thanks for the help, works wonderful now :)